# Glassfish Tools plugin for Eclipse Luna SR2 not working

Tags: eclipse, plugins, glassfish, eclipse-luna

I always install **Glassfish Tools** using **Eclipse Marketplace** or just downloading additional adapters in Eclipse `Servers > New > Server`.

For some reason, when moving from Eclipse Luna SR1 to SR2, the new plugin doesn't install the adapter (the "New Server" window doesn't shows Glassfish as an option), and when trying to manually download the Glassfish adapter, clicking at `Download additional server adapters...`, the Glassfish adapter is not shown.

Is there any bug in this version?
Something has changed in Oracle that the plugin is not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are running Eclipse with Java 8. The latest version of GF Tools for Eclipse requires Java 8 to run. You can still compile your projects with an earlier version of Java, if that's necessary.

To check the version of Java that you are running, go to Help -> About -> Installation Details -> Configuration.

To force Eclipse to use a particular JRE install, edit eclipse.ini file and add the following two lines at the start of the file:

```
-vm
[path-to-jre]
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you!
I had JDK 8 but an older version (8u21, I think). I just updated it and it worked. No VM args needed.