# How to add glassfish tools to eclipse oxygen 3a

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I downloaded Eclipse Oxygen but i don't get glassfish tools installed in this IDE.

It's a Oxygen 3A 64 bit running on a JDK 8 Update 172.

When i try to install the tools via Marketplace it states that the tools are not available.

[Screenshot Marketplace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU5pr.png)

[Screenshot error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5ZfX.png)

Here the Entry in the Eclipse Error Log for this:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.7.3.M20180330-0640
java.version=1.8.0_172
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui
Error
Mon Jun 18 17:27:38 CEST 2018
The following solutions are not available: GlassFish Tools (id=oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.feature.group, site=http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/oxygen)
```

I already tried this: [Glassfish Tools plugin for Eclipse Luna SR2 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309035/glassfish-tools-plugin-for-eclipse-luna-sr2-not-working)

and this: [How to add GlassFish Server to Eclipse Oxygen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641337/how-to-add-glassfish-server-to-eclipse-oxygen)

Without success.

Any Ideas? Maybe the download location changed? But to where?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the Solution on the Oracle Website.

There's a Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html

On this Site there's also the Link to the repository:
http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.2.1.8/oxygen/repository/

In the Eclipse IDE paste this Link in the **Work with:**-Textfield under **Help**->**Install new Software...**

GlassFish Tools are contained in the **Oracle Jave EE Tools** under **Tools**.

Comment: To confirm that even when link contains `oxygen`, it works without any problem for `eclipse-jee-2018-12-R`

Comment: Just this worked in Eclipse March 2020, Installing Sapphire 9.1.1 before Glassfish Tools not required

Answer (score 10):

You need to install Sapphire 9.1.1 before installing the GlassFish Tools.

To install:

1. Open Eclipse
2. Click on Help option
3. Click Install New Software
4. Work with: https://download.eclipse.org/sapphire/9.1.1/repository/
5. Hit Enter on your keyboard
6. Select Sapphire
7. Install
8. Eclipse should restart after completing the installation process.

Then follow the same steps to install GlassFish but for step 4 use the following link for GlassFish to Work with https://download.eclipse.org/glassfish-tools/1.0.1/repository/

Reference: https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/webtools.glassfish-tools/downloads

Comment: Thank you.  Your solution worked for me ... ubuntu 16.04,  JDK 1.8.0,  Eclipse Oxygen build 4.11.0.   Using the link in the "accepted" answer was trying to install both Glassfish and Sapphire at same time which did not work.   Clearly, sapphire needs to be installed BEFORE Glasshfish as you suggested.

Comment: Thank you! It worked with newer eclipse Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)